# Create a windows 10 usb in Ubuntu

Tags: bootable-media

I am trying to create a Windows 10 USB from an Ubuntu Machine following this : https://linuxhint.com/create_windows_10_installer_usb_linux/

As you can see the guide is extremely simple. The thing is the USB is no booting up.

This is the info about it :

```
[~]@main #> lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb    8:16   1  7,3G  0 disk /media/matias/CCCOMA_X64FRE_ES-ES_DV9

[~]@main #> lsblk -t /dev/sdb
NAME ALIGNMENT MIN-IO OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED       RQ-SIZE  RA WSAME
sdb          0    512      0     512     512    1 mq-deadline       2 128    0B

sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 7,27 GiB, 7803174912 bytes, 15240576 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 2.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use command line for this. You can use GUI for creating bootable USB. First open GNOME Disks. Then in the left pane, click your USB drive. In the right area, click the spacr and right click to. Then click Format. Set quick format as erase method and GPT as partitioning scheme if you are using UEFI. Then perform the format with NTFS filesystem. Then again click the unallocated space. Then click + button. Now to create the partition, select the entire space and create. Once created, the file system of USB drive gets automatically mounted. Then mount the windows 10 disk image and extract it to the USB drive. Now reboot and use the key to enter UEFI Firmware. Now in the Boot tab, set boot priority of your USB drive's UEFI (Not legacy) boot at the top. Or if there is a method to select the boot device, then select boot device from that.

Hope that helps

Comment: Ill try to follow this.

Comment: I get an error. I have posted such :(

Comment: Choose a larger USB Drive, you need a USB drive sized more than 8 GB for installing ubuntu.

Comment: And while formatting, choose filesystem as NTFS, because max file size on FAT32 is 4 GB. Install.wim is of 4.3 GB.

Comment: See the edited answer for more information and remove the image from question

Comment: Well I tried with a Kingston of 16GB. Several times. With both GTP and DOS partiion tables as I read in anothe thread. Never worked. I also read I should disable CSM in the bios, and I tried. It did not work either. Ill ask someone with Windows tomorrow to create a USB for me.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.